# Zero à esquerda no R

Tags: r

Tenho um código que pega um arquivo txt com delimitador ";" e trocar pelo "/t". Porém, nesses 90 arquivos, existem campos com id = 01,02,03,04 ...  Quando faço a troca de delimitador os campos com o id acima vem 1,2,3,4,5. Ocorre que necessito preciso desses zeros na frente dessas id.

```
fns = list.files(patt="\\.txt")

n <- length(fns) # Conta o numero de itens na lista

for (i in 1:n){
  dado1 <- read.table(fns[i], head=T,sep=";",encoding = "UTF-8")
  names(dado1)[grep("ï..ID", names(dado1))] <- "ID"
  names(dado1)[grep("X.U.FEFF.ID", names(dado1))] <- "ID"
  #dado1$FL_INPUT[which( is.na(dado1$FL_INPUT))] <- "1"
  excluir <- c("FL_INPUT", "FL_VALIDACAO_LISTAGEM")
  dado1 <- dado1[,!(names(dado1)%in% excluir)]
  write.table(dado1, fns[i], sep="\t", row.names = FALSE, quote=FALSE, na= "", dec = ",")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/how-to-add-leading-zeros) há algumas opções. Você poderia usar:

```
b <- 01
paste0("0",b)
```

ou ainda:

```
formatC(b, width=2, format="d", flag="0")
```

o que resulta em:

```
[1] 1
[1] "01"
[1] "01"
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mano resolveu <3

Comment: Que bom :) não se esqueça de aceitar a resposta então

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer isso com `sprintf`:

```
id <- 1:20
sprintf("%02d", id)
# [1] "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
#[13] "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20"
```